# Retrieving specific values from nested object

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How can I get `Pro_photourl` and `id` values from the following std class?

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [Pro_photourl] => http://122.165.117.41/Commercial_Affairs/api/uploads/hd-panasonic-corporate16.jpg 
    [Pro_photoid] => 1150
  ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object (
    [Pro_photourl] => http://122.165.117.41/Commercial_Affairs/api/uploads/beautiful-wallpaper-3948.jpg
    [Pro_photoid] => 1150
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
    [id] => 1150
    [Pro_userid] => 252
    [Pro_Listingtype] => Paid Listing
    [Pro_membertype] => Owner
    [Pro_purpose] => Rent
    [Pro_type] => Business center
    [Pro_subttype] => Commercial
    [Pro_city] => Kochi
    [Pro_locality] => Kerala, India
    [Pro_society] =>
    [Pro_addr_next] => kochi
    [Pro_facility_washroom] =>
    [Pro_facility_rooms] =>
    [Pro_facility_rating] =>
    [Pro_facility_balcony] =>
    [Pro_facility_pooja_Room] =>
    [Pro_facility_study_Room] =>
    [Pro_facility_servant_Room] =>
    [Pro_facility_others] =>
    [Pro_furnishing] => Yes
    [Pro_numberofproperty] => 1
    [Pro_buildarea] => 700
    [Pro_buildareaunit] => Sq.ft
    [Pro_plotarea] => 0
    [Pro_Plotareaunit] => NA
    [Pro_carpetarea] =>
    [Pro_carpetareaunit] =>
    [Pro_price_crore] =>
    [Pro_price_lakhs] =>
    [Pro_price_thousand] =>
    [Pro_pricefull] => 1000
    [Pro_allprice] => YES
    [Pro_pricenogotable] =>
    [Pro_maintcharge] => 0
    [Pro_maint_pmtmethod] =>
    [Pro_transtype] => NA
    [Pro_ownershiptype] => freehold
    [Pro_availability] => readyToMove
    [Pro_possessionperiod] => NA
    [Pro_photoid] =>
    [Pro_featuresid] =>
    [Pro_description] => Test
    [Pro_phonehide_disp] => yes
    [Pro_regdate] => 2016-09-30 18:43:58
    [Pro_bookingamt] =>
    [Pro_anualduepayable] =>
    [Pro_distfromairport] =>
    [Pro_distfromHospital] =>
    [Pro_distfromrailwaystation] =>
    [Pro_distfromATM] =>
    [Pro_Distfromcitycenter] =>
    [Pro_distfromschool] =>
    [Pro_keylandmark] =>
    [Pro_adlcomments] =>
    [Pro_verified] => Yes
    [Pro_status] => Active
    [Pro_unitprice] => 10000
    [Pro_age] =>
    [Expiry_Date] => 0
  )
)
```

Comment: foreach($result as $key=>$row){        echo $row->Pro_photourl;   echo $row->Pro_photoid;    }

Comment: simple: `foreach ($yourArr as $value) {
    echo $value->Pro_photourl;
}`

Comment: try my answers @cyriac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get values of `Pro_photourl` and `id` from std class, you can just use:

```
<?php
foreach ($yourArr as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($value->Pro_photourl)){
        echo $value->Pro_photourl; // will print photourl if exist in object
    }
    if(isset($value->id)){
        echo $value->id; // will print id if exist in object.
    }    
}
?>
```

*Because as per your `array` you have three index, two indexes having `Pro_photourl` and only one index having `id` value.*

Comment: Thank you guys...got the output...got the best@devpro,@JYoThI

Comment: @cyriac: glad to help u friend,

Comment: @cyriac: i have no issue to accept any best answer, this is your choice, but answer you have accepted update 5 minutes ago and i have shared my answer 18 minutes ago, jyothl just update the answer after checking my answer LOL. :)

Comment: @devpro can you look user post below comment . there i was placed my answer before one 1 minute faster than  your comment . there is no need to check your answer . and i have no issue to accept any answer. i'm cool

Comment: @JYoThI: this is not about the reward, i have already mentioned to choose best answer not mine. so cool to and u also deserve for this

Answer (score 2):

just use `foreach` used to loop through each key/value pair

```
foreach($result as $key=>$row)
{ 
   if(isset($row->Pro_photourl))
   {
    echo $row->Pro_photourl;
   }

   if(isset($row->Pro_userid))
   {
     echo $row->Pro_userid; 
   }

   if(isset($row->id))
   {
     echo $row->id; 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to browse through elements   (using $arr as your object array variable)

```
foreach($arr as $element){
    echo $element->Pro_photourl;
    echo $element->Pro_photoid;
}




//use 
$arr[2]->id;
$arr[2]->Pro_userid
```

Comment: I'm trying to get Pro_photourl and id

Comment: [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1150 [Pro_userid] => 252

Comment: use

`$arr[2]->id`
`$arr[2]->Pro_userid`